# validity of simple argument for showing $\sum 1/p$ grows like $\log \log x$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

I am trying to develop an argument that $\sum 1/p$ grows like $\log \log x$ for $p\leq x$ that is accessible to students without university training in mathematics.

I would like comment on its validity, especially the last step.

---

**Step 1:**

Let's start with the product formula.

$$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n}\frac{1}{n^{s}}=\prod_{n}\left(\frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}\right)$$

Turning products into sums by taking logarithms is a good habit.

$$\log\zeta(s)=-\sum_{p}\ln(1-p^{-s})$$

---

**Step 2:**

We can use the power series $\ln(1-x)=-x-\frac{x^{2}}{2}-\frac{x^{3}}{3}-\cdots$ for $|x|<1$ to expand the logarithm.

$$\begin{align}\ln\zeta(s)&=\sum_{p}(\frac{1}{p^{s}}+\frac{1}{2p^{2s}}+\frac{1}{3p^{3s}}+\frac{1}{4p^{4s}}\ldots) \\ &=\sum_{p}\frac{1}{p^{s}}+C\end{align}$$

The expansion gives us $\sum1/p^{s}$ which looks promising. The rest of the expansion converges to a constant $C$.

---

**Step 3:**

How do we know $C$ converges? We know $\sum\frac{1}{n^{x}}$, converges if $x>1$, and because $s>1$ this is also true for $\sum1/n^{ks}$ for $k\geq2$. Any series $\sum\frac{1}{p^{x}}$, summing only over primes p and not all integers $n$, also converges because it is a subseries of $\sum\frac{1}{n^{x}}$.

---

**Step 4:**

Let's see what happens if we set $s=1$. The rest of the series still converges to a constant, let's call it $D$, because the smallest $ks$ in $\sum1/p^{ks}$ is 2.

$$\ln\left(\sum\frac{1}{n}\right)=\sum_{p}\frac{1}{p}+D$$

Now, we know from integral comparison tests that $\sum1/n$ grows like $\ln(n)$, so $\ln\sum1/n$ must grow like $\ln\ln(n)$.

Since $D$ is a constant, this suggests $\sum1/p$ grows like $\ln\ln(n)$ for $p\leq n$.

---

**Discussion:**

The reason I am posting this question is that I think there is merit in step 4.

We know the LHS $\sum\frac{1}{n}$ diverges, but we also know that as $n$ grows, the sum grows like $\ln n$. We can then say that $\ln\left(\sum\frac{1}{n}\right)$ grows like $\ln \ln(n)$. **Is this correct?**

We know the RHS $\sum_{p}\frac{1}{p}+D$ diverges, but since it derived using the same mathematical operations as the LHS, it also grows in the same way as the LHS. **Is this correct?**

If the last statement is correct, because $D$ is known to converge, we can then conclude $\sum 1/p$ grows like $\ln \ln(n)$ for $p \leq n$.

There might be a question about the different ranges for the LHS and RHS. The LHS is up to $n$, and the RHS is up to $p$. I believe the argument can be made to equate them such that the common function domains is $p \leq n$. **Is this correct?**

I appreciate your patience with me on this, I hope you will value my persistence on this, and not giving up learning mathematics!

---

**Note** - I have asked a similar question before [[link]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4061112/validity-of-simple-intuition-for-sum-1-p-sim-log-log-n-work), but I feel this question is different and more specific.

Comment: Note that the $C$ of step $2$ is a function of $s$, which however has the nice property of being defined and continuous at $s=1$ (which is basically what step $3$ says). Step 4 isn’t great however. When taking $s=1$, you’re just writing $\infty=\infty$ – there’s not much that allows you to truncate the sums (a priori). What grows like $\ln{n}$ (for instance) is $\sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{1}{k}}$ (the finite sum). Still, it’s not too bad a heuristic to say that the asymptotic behavior of the divergent positive series $\sum{a_n}$ is correlated to the asymptotics as $s\rightarrow 1$ of $\sum{a_n^s}$.

Comment: So step 4 may well be able to be mended. I think your overall argument was Euler’s intuition about the series of inverses of prime numbers.

Comment: hi @Mindlack thanks for a really helpful comment. So to clarify, even thought both sides diverge, knowing *how* the LHS diverges doesn't doesn't inform us about how the RHS diverges. I find this difficult to understand but I will think about it. If I imagine a different $X(s)=Y(s)$ which diverges as $s\rightarrow1$, and if I know how $X$ diverges surely I know how $Y$ diverges too?

Comment: the main problem with this argument is that when you do $\prod_{p \le x}\left(\frac{1}{1-p^{-1}}\right)$ there is no immediate correlation to $\sum_{n \le x} 1/n$ in the sense that yes you get those terms since any $n \le x$ is in that product, but you get much more since you get products of primes that break $n$ and the trick is to show that you actually get roughly a multiple of that and not more

Comment: Thans @Conrad I think I am starting to understand now.

Comment: @TariqRashid: I'll try to be more philosophical than technical, since others have done it better. Briefly, you're using two different "metrics" of divergence: the usual one (the behavior of the partial sum $\sum_{k=1}^n{a_k}$as $n$ goes to infinity) and something more subtle (the asymptotics of $\sum_{n \geq 1}{a_n^s}$ as $s \rightarrow 1$). Your equality shows that the series on both sides diverge in a similar way using the second metric -- but then you have to rephrase the results in terms of the first metric. It's elementary for the LHS, $s=1+1/\ln{n}$, less so for the RHS.

Comment: @Mindlack this explanation of two different metric of divergence is the core of the matter. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

- Euler was wrong. Why do you write "grow like" instead of $\sum_{n\le x} \frac1n \sim \log x$? It implies that $\log(\sum_{n\le x} \frac1n) \sim \log\log x$ which doesn't tell anything about $\sum_{p\le x} \frac1p$.
- There is only one elementary proof of the Mertens theorem $\sum_{p\le x} \frac1p \sim \log\log x$ whose main step is $$n\log n\sim \log n! =\sum_{p^k\le n} \lfloor n/p^k\rfloor\log p \sim n \sum_{p^k\le n}\frac{\log p}{p^k}$$ where the last step needs $\sum_{p^k\le n}\log p =O(n)$ which follows from $\sum_{p\in (n,2n]}\log p\le \log{2n\choose n}=O(n)$.
- Followed by a partial summation to go from $\sum_{p\le x} \frac{\log p}{p}\sim\log x$ to $\sum_{p\le x} \frac1{p} \sim \log\log x$